# how to force all component in one row?

Tags: plotly-dash

I like to put all the below 4 components in one row, so I used dbc.Row() with nested dbc.Col() with width defined. The final result look very ugly. I remember the total width must be 12, is it correct? why it does’t work for this code? Could you please give me some idea? Thanks

```
            html.Div(
                [
                dbc.Row(
                    [
                    dbc.Col(dbc.Label('Depth Grouping'),width=4),
                    dbc.Col(dcc.Textarea(
                    id='depth-grouping-text',
                    value='2',   
                    style={'width': '100%', 'height': 30},
                            ),width=2
                    ),
                    dbc.Col(dbc.Label('Min Depth'),width=2.5),
                    dbc.Col(dcc.Input(id="min-well-depth-text", type="number", value=0,placeholder=0),width=3.5),
                    ],justify='center'
                )
                ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The "width" parameter inside dbc.Col accepts type int between 1-12. You're trying to pass float values. So, for example, if you'd like to cover the whole width of the row with these 4 columns you try something like this:

```py
html.Div(
                [
                    dbc.Row(
                        [
                            dbc.Col(
                                dbc.Label('Depth Grouping'),
                                width=1
                            ),
                            dbc.Col(
                                dcc.Textarea(
                                    id='depth-grouping-text',
                                    value='2',   
                                    style={'width': '100%', 'height': 30},
                                ),
                                width=5
                            ),
                            dbc.Col(
                                dbc.Label('Min Depth'),
                                width=1
                            ),
                            dbc.Col(
                                dcc.Input(
                                    id="min-well-depth-text",
                                    type="number", 
                                    style={"width":"100%"}, 
                                    value=0,
                                    placeholder=0
                                ),
                                width=5
                            ),
                        ],justify='center'
                    )
                ]  
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep all components in one row, you can follow these steps:

1. Remove the outer container that wraps all components.
2. Use the `dbc.Row` component without the default margin and padding, by setting the `no_gutters` attribute to True.
3. Make sure the total width of all components adds up to 12, as this is the maximum allowed width for a row. Adjust the widths accordingly if needed.
4. Use the `justify` attribute in `dbc.Row` to evenly distribute the components across the row. You can choose from options like `start/center/end/between` and `around` to align the components as desired.

   ```
        dbc.Row(no_gutters=True,
            [
            dbc.Col(dbc.Label('Depth Grouping'),width=2),
            dbc.Col(dcc.Textarea(
            id='depth-grouping-text',
            value='2',   
            style={'width': '100%', 'height': 30},
                    ),width=2
            ),
            dbc.Col(dbc.Label('Min Depth'),width=4),
            dbc.Col(dcc.Input(id="min-well-depth-text", type="number", value=0,placeholder=0),width=4),
            ],justify='around'
        )
   ```

Comment: Thanks Afzal, you said remove the other container which is html.Div(), why? any reason? also what is the purpose of no_gutters? Thanks

Comment: also I got an error: TypeError: The `dash_bootstrap_components.Row` component (version 1.5.0) received an unexpected keyword argument: `no_gutters`